# Category URL Key redirect to Product Link

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category, url

For example, I have this category that I want to redirect it to product page, is this possible?

For example I have Kati Birch Forest product, and it's url key is kati-birch-forest

[image]

Then I want this Corporate Gifts Url key **redirects** to kati-birch-forest product **INSTEAD** of the category's own url key.

[image]

How do we do this? Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by "URL Rewrite Management"

**Catalog->URL Rewrite Management-> Click "Add URL Rewrite" button**
Then
Select "For Category" -> Select a category you want to rewrite to product page.

[image]

Then enter your product url in 4th field "**Request Path**".
here **hoodies.html** is my product URL: **http://localhost.com/magento/hoodies.html** and
then Select "redirect permanent 301" from the list "Redirect".

[image]

Comment: This will not work, request path should be unique, if you have it already defined to navigate to category, you can't have another entry to reach to product.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this, you need to do url forwarding either by .htaccess file or from CDN if using any.
This can't be done by Magento only.
Easy way to do is creating the url redirection entries in .htaccess file.